# Getting details from cloudtrail

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudtrail

I must be missing something obvious. But I am not able to get the details of the error.

[image]

There is no way to know exact error returned by lambda.

Comment: Per this AWS [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/monitoring-aws-lambda-errors-using-amazon-cloudwatch/) you may be able to use the "CloudWatch console, utilize Logs Insights to query platform logs that Lambda sends for each function execution."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per this AWS [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/monitoring-aws-lambda-errors-using-amazon-cloudwatch/) you should be able to use the "CloudWatch console, utilize Logs Insights to query platform logs that Lambda sends for each function execution."

Comment: Is it possible to get an email alert when there is any error?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/get-notified-specific-lambda-function-error-patterns-using-cloudwatch/

Comment: Is there a cloudformation template that will generate resources mentioned in the above blog post? adding a bounty of 100 points.

Comment: I guess I need to use a third party service like lumigo.io to watch telemetry API. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-the-aws-lambda-telemetry-api/